# Text to speech class showing error (android)

Tags: android

Hi i am a newbie in android development ,i am creating a sms and call reader application in which i have used a service in which i have used Text to speech class. And i am getting an error **speak failed: not bound to TTS Engine**. Can anyone help ?
Thanks

```
Texttospeech.java

package com.example.sms_reader;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;

public class Myservice extends Service{
     TextToSpeech tts;
     String   content2;
     public void onCreate() {       
        super.onCreate();
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, null);

     }               
     public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            //TODO do something useful        
             Log.d("tag4", "INTENT RECEIVED");
             content2 = intent.getStringExtra("content");       
             Log.d("tag6", content2);
             speakOut(); 

         return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;

     }


private void speakOut() {


    tts.speak(content2, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}   

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Don't forget to shutdown!
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void onInit(int status) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

        // tts.setPitch(5); // set pitch level

        // tts.setSpeechRate(2); // set speech speed rate

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "Language is not supported");
        } 
        else {

            speakOut();
        }

                                         } 
    else 
    {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed");
    }

}

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace tts = new TextToSpeech(this, null); by tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

Comment: Replace public class Myservice extends Service{  with public class Myservice extends Service implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{

and add overriden annotation ( @Override ) to init() method

Comment: @Ajit- now application is working but still it is showing the same error. And it says the name only once when one ring is complete and another ring starts it didn't say the name

Comment: what is mean by that it is working bur still it is showing same error. Now what is exactly is the problem.